# Require password on update with Knock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I'm trying to require the user's current password when they update their user record with Knock. I thought that I could run their submitted password through the same process as what creates password_digest, but whenever I compare the hashes created, they are different. Am I missing something when hashing the user input?

This is my update method

```
def update

  @user = current_user

  # hash current password
  @current_password = params[:current_password]
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
  @hashed_password = BCrypt::Password.create(@current_password, cost: cost)


  # return if no current password is given
  if @current_password != nil

    # compare and continue if they match
    if @hashed_password === current_user.password_digest

      # try to update record
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        render json: @user
      else
        render json: @user.errors.full_messages
      end

    # otherwise return password error
    else
      render json: { message: "Your current password is incorrect" }
    end

  else
    render json: { message: "You must provide your current password" }
  end
end
```

**Edit:** The user is saved with `has_secure_password` on the user model, which if I understand correctly, triggers [this call](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L114) in ActiveModel. I used byebug to stop execution and compare the variables after assignment, they are in fact different.

**Edit 2:** If anyone runs across this in the future and wants to use a similar strategy, you need to add `attr_accessor :current_password` to your User model so that it will let you pass the `current_password` param to evaluate.

Comment: Where is the original password being hashed? Is the logic the same? Also why are you using `===` instead of `==` for comparison? Please add more code related to the original password being hashed. Have you tried using `pry-rails` to stop execution and check the values at `@hashed_password` and `current_user.password_digest`?

Comment: I added a link to the original method that hashes the user password before save. I've checked them, they are different values. Is case equality not appropriate here?

Comment: `===` is object equity. For example `"foo" === "foo"` is false unless the strings are frozen since they are different objects. `"foo" == "foo"` compares the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Bcrypt repeatedly will not produce the same output even with the same input. Rather there is a large number of possible outputs for any given combination which makes a brute force attack far more costly.

To check if the input is the correct password use `BCrypt::Password#is_password?`

```
BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest).is_password?(unencrypted_password)
```

Since you are using ActiveModel::SecurePassword you can check the password with `@user.authenticate(password)`.

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  unless @user.authenticate(params[:current_password])
    @user.errors.add(:current_password, "is incorrect")
  end 
  if @user.update(user_params)
    render json: @user
  else
    render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: :unproccessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: Both worked perfectly! Thank you, the include helps to clean things up as well.

Comment: I saw that you where using ActiveModel::SecurePassword on a second read through.

Comment: Hmm, actually, when I try to replace the if statements with the unless in this edit, it will accept any password now. Would be awesome to get it refactored like this though, so clean :) This is the last working code that I have based on your answer https://pastebin.com/kU83EWLe

Comment: Ooops should be `@user.authenticate(params[:current_password])`

Comment: But authenticate should return false unless the password is valid in which case it returns the user.

Comment: You don't all that junk you have in your pastebin. Just find out why the call to authenticate is not having the expected result.

Comment: Ok, I stepped through the code as best I could, from what I can tell, the unless statement does evaluate to false, but then pushes the user info to errors and since there's nothing to stop update from saving, the record is saved (no matter what the password is). This is my working code https://pastebin.com/yZ3JFcLS. I added one other edit, I had an error because `current_password` is not a part of the user table (as it shouldn't be with Knock) but this change alone didn't make the code above run. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can compare Bcrypt passwords. Bcrypt is a hashing algorithm, it generates a [unique salt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/password.rb#L46) key on every create which is used by the [hash_secret](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/engine.rb#L45). This makes the hashes different each time. Eg

```
irb(main):010:0> instance = BCrypt::Password.create('secret')
=> "$2a$10$FT8YdmzJIkOceKhZ/DwXluYNGm.lZj0Jfrx2nQqzxxM1IX767gNmG"
irb(main):011:0> instance_two = BCrypt::Password.create('secret')
=> "$2a$10$ECA8HoTSuxAvAbFbbg6jQ.g4uIcZqYbNCckfGIzLePfSTx2OM0zJS"
irb(main):012:0> instance == instance_two
=> false
irb(main):013:0>
```